# Why does "appendChild" moves a node?

Tags: javascript, treenode

I'm playing around with native javascript. I'm basically practicing basic node manipulations such -- add, remove, move, copy, and create.

While testing move, I got a question.

http://jsfiddle.net/sJg7E/

if you look at the jsfiddle above, I've used "appendChild". How come it moves a node to a new div? I know that I need to clone a node if I want to copy a node. It just doesn't look/sound right with "appendChild" command.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: appendchild won't clone a node. if you repeatedly appendchild the SAME node, then you're just moving it around. you need to clone THEN append to get new independent nodes.

Comment: Well a node can only have one parent at a time, so if you append a node to a new parent then it can't have the old one as a parent anymore.

Comment: @Pointy // that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A node can only have one parent. Therefore it moves it if you appends it to another node.

From [documentation of appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild):

> Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent
>   node. If the node already exists it is removed from current parent
>   node, then added to new parent node.

From the same page:

> You can use cloneNode to make a copy of the node before appending it
>   under the new parent. (Note that the copies made with cloneNode will
>   not be automatically kept in sync.)

Also note:

> This method is not allowed to move nodes between different documents.
>   If you want to append node from a different document (for example to
>   display results from AJAX request) you must first use importNode.

You can also read the w3c specification of [appendChild](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107):

> Adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this
>   node. If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed.